# bundle install fails with SSL certificate verification error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, rubygems, bundler

When I run `bundle install` for my Rails 3 project on Centos 5.5 it fails with an error:

```
Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 
read server certificate B: certificate verify failed 
(https://bb-m.rubygems.org/gems/multi_json-1.3.2.gem)
An error occured while installing multi_json (1.3.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install multi_json -v '1.3.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

When I try to install the gem manually (by `gem install multi_json -v '1.3.2'`) it works. The same problem occurs with several other gems. I use RVM (1.12.3), ruby 1.9.2, bundler 1.1.3.

How to fix it?

Comment: Facing the same problem. But with another gem: Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://bb-m.rubygems.org/gems/activeresource-3.2.3.gem)

Comment: I am having the same error with the same circumstances. I suspect, given these other responses, that it's a server-side issue.

Comment: I had a similar problem in Rails 5. Fixed it by adding `source 
"https://rubygems.org''` in the Gemfile and running 'gem update --system'.  You can find more info [here](https://kolosek.com/rails-bundle-install-and-gemfile).

Answer (score 314, accepted):

**Update**

Now that I've karma wh..err mined enough from this answer everyone should know that this should have been fixed.

re: via Ownatik again [bundle install fails with SSL certificate verification error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246023/bundle-install-fails-with-ssl-certificate-verification-error/10430331#10430331)

```
gem update --system
```

My answer is still correct and left below for reference if that ends up not working for you.

---

Honestly the best temporary solution is to

> [...] use the non-ssl version of rubygems in your gemfile as a temporary workaround.

via user Ownatik

what they mean is at the top of the `Gemfile` in your rails application directory change

`source 'https://rubygems.org'`

to

`source 'http://rubygems.org'`

note that the second version is http instead of http**s**

Comment: I'm accepting this answer, because that was the thing that I did at first. Later I changed my deploy strategy. Now I run bundle the application on another server and then I copy it (with gems in `vendor` directory) to the server I wrote about in the question.

Comment: This didn't work for me. [The link](http://railsapps.github.com/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html) provided by @fbernier below fixed it for me.

Comment: I also had to follow that link by @fbernier, particularly in that page's "alternative" section

Comment: This doesn't work.  Running this just provides output of `Latest version currently installed. Aborting.`  Any other ideas?

Comment: Read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16913828/ssl-connect-returned-1-errno-0-state-sslv3-read-server-certificate-b-certifica) TL;DR: `apt-get install openssl ca-certificates`

Comment: In terms of changing the source, for newer people like me. I would specify that this file is located in your application directory. I was looking for it in the railsinstaller directory. Anyways, I changed the source and it finally worked. I am getting certificate errors when I try to run the update :(

Comment: This did not work for me. Using Debian Jessie within Docker. Ruby 2.1.5p273, Gem 2.4.5, Bundler 1.7.8

Comment: With certificate issues: changing the source to insecure: gem sources -a http:// rubygems.org/ (don't forget to put secure back)

Comment: `gem update --system` fails with the exact same certificate error :\

Comment: This is an application-specific solution. Flextra provided a true solution.

Comment: @Paul. I said in my answer this is a temporary solution. Thanks for pointing to Flextra's answer. Hopefully that works for others. I will still leave mine here because sometimes those other solutions dont work for everyone. This works regardless of external factors. and for someone who is just learning rails and just wants things to work that is fine

Comment: perfect answer, i had spent a lot of time searching for this answer

Comment: Hey can anyone please tell me where can we find the Gemfile in Ruby,it would be thanks if u specify the path

Comment: just incase if you are using RVM and the above solution doesnt work (which happened to me). just run `rvm osx-ssl-certs update all`. This wil update all certificates. more info here ->
http://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html

Comment: @sujay that doesn't seem to help. I get the same error as Danny.

Comment: This sent me into a whole world of needing new RVM and bundler and ruby...

Comment: I experience `Bundler::Fetcher::CertificateFailureError Could not verify the SSL certificate for https://rubygems.org/` because we have enterprise Sophos firewall and I must somehow install Sophos certificate into gem system so that bundler will use it. How to do this?

Answer (score 229):

Replace the ssl gem source with non-ssl as a temp solution:

- gem sources -r https://rubygems.org/
- gem sources -a http://rubygems.org/

Comment: OMG worked like a charm! I'm on Windows 7 x64 behind a corporate proxy. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm surprised this was not ranked higher, this was the easiest quick fix.

Comment: good temp solution...be aware of the following ::
RubyGems has been configured to serve gems via the following URLs through its history:
* http://gems.rubyforge.org (RubyGems 1.3.6 and earlier)
* http://rubygems.org       (RubyGems 1.3.7 through 1.8.25)
* https://rubygems.org      (RubyGems 2.0.1 and newer)

Comment: fastest solution for me on Windows 8

Comment: Problem is that it still attempts to get gem metadata from the https source.  Any way to override this?

Comment: @RaySuelzer the path should match exactly that string that in your options. type `gem sources` and watch actial value. then remove it. then add non https. anyway read my comment to be sure of desired behaviour.

Comment: Also, make sure you're not MITMing yourself.  I forgot I was running Charles Proxy.  /facepalm

Comment: Imho this should not even be considered a valid answer, because it opens up your system to attacks from outside.

Comment: Works on Windows 10 ! It's not the safest solution but really works.

Comment: This one won't work anymore. Guys at rubygems put stricter settings in place and non-http version is now redirected to https automatically since couple days ago.

Answer (score 163):

The reason is old rubygems. You need to update system part using non ssl source first:

`gem update --system --source http://rubygems.org/` (temporarily updating system part using non-ssl connection).

Now you're ready to use `gem update`.

Comment: Really simple solution that's cross-platform and allows RubyGems to take care of the details. Nice.

Comment: this was the one that should be accepted, the answers above don't explain that you need to remove the ssl sources first

Comment: Thanks - this is the ticket.  If you get a "not in cache" message when adding or removing sources, try it with or without a trailing slash.  It has to match exactly.

Comment: I have searched trough many solutions. This is the one worked like a charm. Thank you! This should be choosen as the true solution.

Comment: Thank you!! I agree with others that this should be the accepted answer, as it doesn't result in you fetching gems through plain HTTP.

Comment: if it is temporary fix why not to add `--source http://rubygems.org/`at the end of your install command?

Comment: @user3705055 thanks, please, review changes for correctness.

Comment: November 2016, and yet, this is still the only answer that works. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me (somehow still get an SSL error). EDIT: This worked in conjunction with asfallows' answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10250470/1240268)

Answer (score 118):

If you're on a mac and use a recent version of RVM (~1.20), the following command worked for me.

```
rvm osx-ssl-certs update
```

Comment: Thanks, worked for me too. I was trying to install CocoaPods. rvm 1.22.15, OS X 10.8.5

Comment: This is also pointed to in the error message "...see bit.ly/ruby-ssl".

Comment: Thankssssss!! Worked for me!! \o/

Answer (score 55):

This issue should now be fixed. Update rubygems (`gem update --system`), make sure openssl is at the latest version on your OS, or try these tips of it's still not working: http://railsapps.github.com/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html

Comment: Needed to update bundler as well to make it work (rubygems 2.0.3 + bundler 1.3.2 + cygwin openssl 1.0.1e works for me on winxp).

Comment: I had to update from 1.3.0, now I am on 1.3.4 and the https is no longer throwing the error:

    bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/vendor/net/http/persistent/ssl_reuse.rb:70:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server key exchange B: bad ecpoint (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)

Comment: It is not possible to update rubygems if the SSL certificate is not accepted! Running in circles here ;)

Answer (score 53):

Temporary solution (as alluded to by Ownatik):

Create or modify a file called .gemrc in your home path, including the line `:ssl_verify_mode: 0`

This will prevent bundler from checking the SSL certificates of gems when it attempts to install them.

For *nix devices, 'home path' means `~/.gemrc`. You can also create `/etc/gemrc` if you prefer. For Windows XP, 'home path' means `c:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\gemrc`. For Windows 7, `C:\ProgramData\gemrc`

Comment: `%USERPROFILE%\.gemrc` is also searched by `gem` on Windows.

Comment: Recommended file location for Windows 8?

Comment: Removing ssl verification is temporary workaround that opens a security hole. Read more here: https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/commit/c7d6c6efd2a9e813eb538d805a6f5780437d7006

Comment: This is useful in my case; behind a corporate firewall that restricts all compressed files but allows them via https.

Comment: Didn't try this solution, but in my case also worked when I added this content to the `~/.gemrc` : `:sources:
 - http://rubygems.org`

Comment: Worked for me. I couldn't use the "gem update --system" fix on our legacy system.

Answer (score 18):

On windows7 you can download the cacert.pem file from [here](http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem) and set the environementvariable SSL_CERT_FILE to the path where you store the certificate eg

```
SET SSL_CERT_FILE="C:\users\<username>\cacert.pem"
```

or you can set the variable in your script like this `ENV['SSL_CERT_FILE']="C:/users/<username>/cacert.pem"`

Replace <username> with you own username.

Comment: Thank you. Permanent fix is here. http://guides.rubygems.org/ssl-certificate-update/

Comment: This is the right permanent fix, and avoiding using unsecured http source.

Answer (score 15):

The real solution to this problem, if you are using RVM:

1. Update rubygems: `gem update --system`
2. Use RVM to refresh SSL certs: `rvm osx-ssl-certs update all`

Hat tip to [this tip on the RailsApps project](http://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html)!

Comment: `rvm osx-ssl-certs update all` worked fine for me. Didnt need to to do step 1.

Answer (score 9):

You can download a list of CA certificates from curl's website at http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

Then set the SSL_CERT_FILE environment variable to tell Ruby to use it. For example, in Linux:

```
$ SSL_CERT_FILE=~/cacert.pem bundle install
```

(Reference: https://gist.github.com/fnichol/867550)

Comment: On Debian Buster I had to do this: `SSL_CERT_FILE=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt gem update --system`

Answer (score 7):

For those of you that have ruby installed through RVM and want a quick fix (preferring not to read per Bruno's request) just try this:

```
rvm remove 1.9.x (or whatever version of ruby you are using)
rvm pkg install openssl
rvm install 1.9.2 --with-openssl-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```

For a more details, here is the link where I found the solution.

http://railsapps.github.com/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html

BTW, I didn't have to touch my certificates on Ubuntu.

> Best of all, this isn't a workaround. It will download gems through
>   SSL and fail if there if there is a problem like a man in the middle
>   attack which is much better than just turning off security.

Comment: The page you link to has a "workaround" (first) and then proper solutions. It would be better if your answer stated that a bit more clearly. Nevertheless, using CA certificates (via `cacert.pem` or `$rvm_path/usr/ssl`) is indeed the right way to go.

Comment: Bruno, the solution will probably be a bit different depending on what flavor of Unix the person uses. It looks like reading the link will be necessary.

Comment: I was just talking about the difference between the "workaround" on the page (`:ssl_verify_mode: 0`, which open problems), as opposed to any of the 3 solutions below it, which are the right way to fix this problem.

Comment: @Bruno, I've revised my article, please add comments or edit the wiki if you see possibilities for improvements.

Answer (score 6):

This has been fixed

http://guides.rubygems.org/ssl-certificate-update/

Now that RubyGems 2.6.x has been released, you can manually update to this version.

Download https://rubygems.org/downloads/rubygems-update-2.6.7.gem

Please download the file in a directory that you can later point to (eg. the root of your harddrive C:)

Now, using your Command Prompt:

```
C:\>gem install --local C:\rubygems-update-2.6.7.gem
C:\>update_rubygems --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

After this, gem --version should report the new update version.

You can now safely uninstall rubygems-update gem:

```
C:\>gem uninstall rubygems-update -x
```

Answer (score 5):

Simple copy paste instruction given here about .pem file

https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88

For  certificate verification failed

> If you've read the previous sections, you will know what this means (and shame > on you if you have not).
>
> We need to download [AddTrustExternalCARoot-2048.pem](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rubygems/rubygems/master/lib/rubygems/ssl_certs/AddTrustExternalCARoot-2048.pem).
>   Open a Command Prompt and type in:
>
> C:>gem which rubygems
>   C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems.rb
>   Now, let's locate that directory. From within the same window, enter the path part up to the file extension, but using backslashes instead:
>
> C:>start C:\Ruby21\lib\ruby\2.1.0\rubygems
>   This will open a Explorer window inside the directory we indicated.
>
> Step 3: Copy new trust certificate
>
> Now, locate ssl_certs directory and copy the .pem file we obtained from previous step inside.
>
> It will be listed with other files like GeoTrustGlobalCA.pem.

Answer (score 4):

same problem but with different gem here:

```
Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 
read server certificate B: certificate verify failed 
(https://bb-m.rubygems.org/gems/builder-3.0.0.gem)
An error occured while installing builder (3.0.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install builder -v '3.0.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

temporarily solution: `gem install builder -v '3.0.0'` makes it possible to continue `bundle install`

Comment: You can also use the non-ssl version of rubygems in your gemfile as a temporary workaround.

Comment: I did it and it works. For now, that's a sufficient solution.

Comment: I have a same problem over here. So @Ownatik how to use ssl version of rubygems?

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution:

```
rvm pkg install openssl
rvm reinstall all --force
```

Voila!

Comment: What does this actually do to my system?

Comment: `rvm pkg` is deprecated now, anyway.

Comment: @labyrinth it gives a warning but still works

Answer (score 4):

This is How you fix this problem on Windows:

download .perm file then set the SSL_CERT_FILE in command prompt

https://gist.github.com/fnichol/867550

Answer (score 4):

My permanent fix for Windows:

1. Download the [CACert](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rubygems/rubygems/master/lib/rubygems/ssl_certs/index.rubygems.org/GlobalSignRootCA.pem) , save as `C:\ruby\ssl_certs\GlobalSignRootCA.pem` from http://guides.rubygems.org/ssl-certificate-update/
2. Create system variable named "**SSL_CERT_FILE**", set to `C:\ruby\ssl_certs\GlobalSignRootCA.pem`.
3. Try again: `gem install bundler`:

> ```
> C:\gem sources
> *** CURRENT SOURCES ***
> https://rubygems.org/
>
> C:\gem install bundler
> Fetching: bundler-1.13.5.gem (100%)
> Successfully installed bundler-1.13.5
> 1 gem installed
> ```

Answer (score 3):

I get a slightly different error, though perhaps related, on Ubuntu 12.04:

```
Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=unknown state: sslv3 alert handshake failure (https://d2chzxaqi4y7f8.cloudfront.net/gems/activesupport-3.2.3.gem)
An error occured while installing activesupport (3.2.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install activesupport -v '3.2.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

It happens when I run `bundle install` with `source 'https://rubygems.org'` in a Gemfile.

This is an issue with OpenSSL on Ubuntu 12.04. See [Rubygems issue #319](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/319#issuecomment-5403091).

To fix this, run `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` on Ubuntu 12.04 to upgrade your OpenSSL.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to track this down to the fact that the binaries that `rvm` downloads do not play nice with OS X's OpenSSL, which is old and is no longer used by the OS.

The solution for me was to force compilation when installing Ruby via `rvm`:

```
rvm reinstall --disable-binary 2.2
```

Comment: This worked for me.  You need to replace "2.2" w/ the ruby version you're using

Answer (score 3):

Thx to @Alexander.Iljushkin for:

`gem update --system --source http://rubygems.org/`

After that bundler still failed and the solution to that was:

`gem install bundler`

Answer (score 2):

I was getting a similar error. Here is how I solved this: In your path directory, check for Gemfile. Edit the source in the gemfile to http instead of https and save it. This might install the bundler without the SSL certificate issue.l

Answer (score 2):

For Windows machine, check your gem version with

```
gem --version
```

Then update your gem as follow:

- Running 1.8.x: [download 1.8.30](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/releases/tag/v1.8.30)
- Running 2.0.x: [download 2.0.15](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/releases/tag/v2.0.15)
- Running 2.2.x: [download 2.2.3](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/releases/tag/v2.2.3)

Please download the file in a directory that you can later point to (eg. the root of your hard drive C:)

Now, using your Command Prompt:

```
C:\>gem install --local C:\rubygems-update-1.8.30.gem
C:\>update_rubygems --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

Now, bundle install will success without SSL certificate verification error.

More detailed instruction is [here](https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88)

Answer (score 2):

### If you're using `rails-assets`

If you were using `https://rails-assets.org/` to manage your assets, no answers will help you. Even converting to `http` won't help.

The simplest fix is using this source instead,  `http://insecure.rails-assets.org`. This has been mentioned in their [homepage](https://rails-assets.org/#/).

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

- download latest gem at https://rubygems.org/pages/download
- install the gem with `gem install --local [path to downloaded gem file]`
- update the gems with `update_rubygems`
- check that you're on the latest gem version with `gem --version`

Answer (score 1):

I had to reinstall openssl:

```
brew uninstall --force openssl
brew install openssl
```

Answer (score 1):

I was just recently faced with this issue and followed the steps outlined [here](https://gemfury.com/help/could-not-verify-ssl-certificate). There might be a chance that you are not pointing to the right OpenSSL certificate. After running:

```
rvm osx-ssl-certs status all
rvm osx-ssl-certs update all
```

and

```
export SSL_CERT_FILE=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

the bundle complete ran!

Answer (score 1):

Download  [rubygems-update-2.6.7.gem](https://rubygems.org/downloads/rubygems-update-2.6.7.gem) .

Now, using your Command Prompt:

```
C:\>gem install --local C:\rubygems-update-2.6.7.gem
C:\>update_rubygems --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

After this, `gem --version` should report the new update version.

You can now safely uninstall rubygems-update gem:

```
C:\>gem uninstall rubygems-update -x
Removing update_rubygems
Successfully uninstalled rubygems-update-2.6.7
```

Answer (score 1):

To note, if you're grabbing gems from a source which SSL cert is trusted by an internal certificate authority (or you are connecting to an external source through a company web proxy with SSL inspection), point your SSL_CERT_FILE env variable to your certificate chain.  This most likely just requires exporting your root certificate from your certificate store (System Keychain on macOS) to an accessible location from your shell i.e.:

```
export SSL_CERT_FILE=~/RootCert.pem
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me on legacy windows system and ruby 1.9 version is downloading cacert file from
http://guides.rubygems.org/ssl-certificate-update/

And then running below command before running bundle install

```
bundle config --global ssl_ca_cert /path/to/file.pem
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up by looking at Rubygems code, add that line to your .gemrc file:

```
:ssl_ca_cert: /<path to your own CA cert >/cacert.cer
```