# "SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed"

Tags: ruby, openssl, certificate, debian, redmine

I'm setting-up Redmine to poll e-mails from gmail via IMAP. An attempt to run the appropriate Ruby task causes the following error:

> SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed

The error occurs when Ruby attempts to connect `imap.gmail.com` via OpenSSL, in the following code line:

```
imap = Net::IMAP.new(host, port, ssl)
```

When I try to connect the above host from OpenSSL command line, it gets connected successfully.

I understand that Ruby doesn't find some certificates and I saw various solution proposals, but unfortunately I still can't figure out how to sort out this issue (I do not use rvm).

I tried to disable the verification by setting `OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE`, but got "dynamic constant assignment" error.

My environment:

```
Linux debianvm 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.41-2+deb7u2 x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@debianvm:~# ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p429 (2013-05-15 revision 40747) [x86_64-linux]
root@debianvm:~# rails --version
Rails 3.2.13
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue has been solved by simply installing root certificates:

```
apt-get install openssl ca-certificates
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the first solution of many that I read and tried that *actually* works! :)

Comment: @Igor R. Any idea how to install on winxp?

Comment: @GuruM I don't know. Should be something like - download the certificate and double-click on it ;).