# Trying to install gems needed to run the twitter Bootstrap gem - getting error while running bundle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, rubygems, dependencies

I have a regular Rails 4 app for which Im trying to incorporate the twitter bootstrap framework.

The relevant parts of my gemfile looks like this:

```
  #Gems used only for assets and not required  in production environments by default
  group :assets do

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  gem "therubyracer", :require => 'v8'

  gem "less-rails", "~> 2.4.2"

  # Use SCSS for stylesheets
  gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

  # Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

  # Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

  gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails", "~> 2.2.8"

  end
```

When I run the bundle command on terminal I get this error:

```
 > bundle
 Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
 Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
 Resolving dependencies...
 Using rake (10.1.0)
 Using i18n (0.6.5)
 Using minitest (4.7.5)
 Using multi_json (1.8.0)
 Using atomic (1.1.14)
 Using thread_safe (0.1.3)
 Using tzinfo (0.3.37)
 Using activesupport (4.0.0)
 Using builder (3.1.4)
 Using erubis (2.7.0)
 Using rack (1.5.2)
 Using rack-test (0.6.2)
 Using actionpack (4.0.0)
 Using mime-types (1.25)
 Using polyglot (0.3.3)
 Using treetop (1.4.15)
 Using mail (2.5.4)
 Using actionmailer (4.0.0)
 Using activemodel (4.0.0)
 Using activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
 Using arel (4.0.0)
 Using activerecord (4.0.0)
 Using annotate (2.5.0)
 Using bundler (1.3.5)
 Using coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
 Using execjs (2.0.2)
 Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
 Using thor (0.18.1)
 Using railties (4.0.0)
 Using coffee-rails (4.0.0)

 Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server 
 certificate B: certificate verify failed 
 (https://s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.rubygems.org/gems/commonjs-0.2.7.gem)

 An error occurred while installing commonjs (0.2.7), and Bundler cannot continue.

 Make sure that `gem install commonjs -v '0.2.7'` succeeds before bundling.
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: You can reference at link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246023/bundle-install-fails-with-ssl-certificate-verification-error

Comment: Hope this link will help you...http://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html

Answer (score 0):

It's common issue on Mac (for me exactly). Try to update openssl:

```
brew update
brew install openssl
```

Sometimes it can also be useful to update symlinks and certificates:

```
brew link openssl --force
brew install curl-ca-bundle
```

If this doesn't help and you are using RVM try to update rvm's certificates:

```
rvm osx-ssl-certs update all
```

Hope this helps!