# Why the SSL connection to the remote server could not be established?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authorize.net, authorize.net-cim

My project is on Ruby On Rails.

I am using `activemerchant gem` for `authorize.net payment gateway`.

Recently I have renewed `SSL license`.

When I am trying to update info it gives me error `The SSL connection to the remote server could not be established`.

I am using `CIM` module for `authorize.net`.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below Links might be helpful:

http://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html

[bundle install fails with SSL certificate verification error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246023/bundle-install-fails-with-ssl-certificate-verification-error)

https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/515

http://www.buildingwebapps.com/articles/79189-using-ssl-in-rails-applications

http://blog.dynamic50.com/2011/02/15/ssl-on-wildcard-domains-on-heroku-using-godaddy/

http://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html