# "certificate verify failed" error when installing Ruby gems on Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, ssl, rubygems

I am using a Windows PC running 8.1 and working with Ruby Installer 2.1.5.

While installing a gem I am getting a error:

```
C:\> gem install bundle
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'bundle' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect retur
ned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (
https://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

I hope there is a good solution.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246023/bundle-install-fails-with-ssl-certificate-verification-error

Comment: Hi Nimir , I just take a look at your link ... and thanks for such a quick reply . but the problem is quite not so same. I am having problem while I am running latest version of RubyInstaller .. :) ..how ever could be that is also related with SSL error ... but lets see ... there is a lot of Guru out there...I can wait for answer

Comment: ok, how about this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150017/ssl-error-when-installing-rubygems-unable-to-pull-data-from-https-rubygems-o

Comment: Taking a good look at it... Thanks Nimir . :) you are awesome..

Comment: Got it here ...  https://gist.github.com/fnichol/867550   thanks Nimir

Comment: Glad you found a work around, btw you can answer and accept your own question to help ppl facing the same issue in the future :)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I had this problem too. But using the older version is not the proper solution.

Here is the two solution help to fix this certificate error

**1. Using the http instead of https will allow you to install the gem without that error**

> gem install bundler -r --source http://rubygems.org/

Comment: Used option 2. Worked like a charm.

Comment: have an upvote, this definitely should be the accepted answer

Comment: Second link is now producing 404 :(

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, it seems the problem is due to ruby installer version (2...) , I tried version 1.9.3  and the problem was solved.