# Rails new app display error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to create new project using rails but it display error. I am working on mac and its display error.

**$rails new EMS**

```
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/rails:23:in `load': cannot load such file -- /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rails-4.2.0/bin/rails (LoadError)
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Are you using Windows as development OS  my friend ?

Comment: what does `which ruby` return ?

Comment: When i fire command **ruby -v** it will return same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One day i also faced same issue when i was trying to create new rails application. So followed these below steps and it was soled,

1. Uninstall the rails
2. Uninstall the ruby
3. Again install the latest version of ruby using `rvm`
4. than install the rails using command `gem install rails`

After following these step, now i am able to create new app. May be this also help you to solve this error.

Comment: Thanks i am able to uninstall rails and reinstall on pc. its work for me..thanks

Comment: Ok the solution is you need to check ruby version on your machine. If its returns error means rails is not install on your machine.The same issue with me so i am install rails on my machine and fix this issue. @Mohammad AbuShady

Comment: @NikhiL what i meant is if this answer helped you solve your problem, then click the check mark on the left under the voting arrows.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using windows OS as your development environment then please see this link : ["certificate verify failed" error when installing Ruby gems on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27380301/error-with-gem-installtion-in-windows-system)

And I would recommend you to use : http://railsinstaller.org/en

By the way , Brother , Rails would behave perfect with Linux based platform .

And for mac os please take a look at : https://rvm.io/rvm/install

This will help you to have multiple ruby version and to switch between them ... to use full power of ruby and gems.

Comment: This all solution for windows but i am using mac...thanks dude