# having problems with railsinstaller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I've been having problems with railsinstaller on my windows 8 laptop which originates from the inability to run the server in the (project) directory using the `rails s` command however contrary to the many tutorials out there, I receive this every time.

```
C:\Sites\demo>rails s
Could not find gem 'tzinfo-data (>= 0) x86-mingw32' in the gems available on thi
s machine.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Then when I try and run bundle install it returns this error.

```
C:\Sites\demo>bundle install
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Resolving dependencies...

Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read
server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.org/gems/rake-
10.4.2.gem)
An error occurred while installing rake (10.4.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rake -v '10.4.2'` succeeds before bundling.

C:\Sites\demo>
```

But everything I have tried to resolve the "FetchError" has been useless.

Could someone please help me with this error?

Comment: Seems duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246023/bundle-install-fails-with-ssl-certificate-verification-error

Answer (score 4):

Seems to be Windows-specific. I had this issue as well and resolved it by upgrading to newest RubyGems.

1. You can download the installer (*zip*) [on RubyGems website](https://rubygems.org/pages/download)
2. Unpack it somewhere you can easily access (let's assume `C:\Ruby\RubyGems`)
3. Bring up your command line (**Win+R**, `cmd`, **Enter**)
4. Get to the directory you unpacked the installer to:
   `cd C:\Ruby\RubyGems`
5. Run `ruby setup.rb`

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing this for your own, In the Gemfile replace the url https://rubygems.org/ as http://rubygems.org.

Comment: what are the downsides for this fix? I did it and it installed the bundles normally.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is comes from the https:// as @Saravanan said. You can fixed this issue using the following command on your ruby on rails command line tool.

```
gem sources -a http://rubygems.org/
```

If you update this source to http:// URL. you would be solve this issue.