# Why won't my gem install when creating a new Ruby on Rails App?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm on a Windows Operating System and I'm trying to create a new Rails app.

When I run rails new, it starts to create the files needed to make the app and then it brings up an error saying that the Rake gem wasn't able to be pulled from the Rubygem website.

Anybody know what the problem could be?

Here's what returned in my command line:

```
$ rails new Connections
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
      create
      create  README.rdoc
      create  Rakefile
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
      create  app
      create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
      create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
      create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
      create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
      create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
      create  app/assets/images/.keep
      create  app/mailers/.keep
      create  app/models/.keep
      create  app/controllers/concerns/.keep
      create  app/models/concerns/.keep
      create  bin
      create  bin/bundle
      create  bin/rails
      create  bin/rake
      create  bin/setup
      create  config
      create  config/routes.rb
      create  config/application.rb
      create  config/environment.rb
      create  config/secrets.yml
      create  config/environments
      create  config/environments/development.rb
      create  config/environments/production.rb
      create  config/environments/test.rb
      create  config/initializers
      create  config/initializers/assets.rb
      create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
      create  config/initializers/cookies_serializer.rb
      create  config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
      create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
      create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
      create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
      create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
      create  config/locales
      create  config/locales/en.yml
      create  config/boot.rb
      create  config/database.yml
      create  db
      create  db/seeds.rb
      create  lib
      create  lib/tasks
      create  lib/tasks/.keep
      create  lib/assets
      create  lib/assets/.keep
      create  log
      create  log/.keep
      create  public
      create  public/404.html
      create  public/422.html
      create  public/500.html
      create  public/favicon.ico
      create  public/robots.txt
      create  test/fixtures
      create  test/fixtures/.keep
      create  test/controllers
      create  test/controllers/.keep
      create  test/mailers
      create  test/mailers/.keep
      create  test/models
      create  test/models/.keep
      create  test/helpers
      create  test/helpers/.keep
      create  test/integration
      create  test/integration/.keep
      create  test/test_helper.rb
      create  tmp/cache
      create  tmp/cache/assets
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.keep
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.keep
         run  bundle install
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Resolving dependencies...

Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read
server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.org/gems/rake-
10.4.2.gem)
An error occurred while installing rake (10.4.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rake -v '10.4.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to update rubygems

```
gem update --system
```

then `bundle install` again

As a workaround, you could bypass the certificate validation by removing the 's' from `https://rubygems.org/` --> `http://rubygems.org/`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the error. if not please correct,

```
read
server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.org/gems/rake-
10.4.2.gem)
```

try these link: 
[having problems with railsinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27470321/having-problems-with-railsinstaller)

[Bundle Install Fails on SSL connect for Rake gem](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/rubyonrails-talk/2HuRVJSNKhw/4PYy0QMVSgsJ)
https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/167648/an-error-occurred-while-installing-rake-1042-and-b.html

https://cindiwritescode.wordpress.com/2014/12/08/getting-up-and-running-with-ruby-on-rails-on-my-local-dev/
[Bundle Install Fails on SSL connect for Rake gem](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/6432416)