# Following RailsBridge Installfest for Windows 8.1 - Failed Installing Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation

I am new to this forum and web development :-) Career change.... I am having problems with the installation. I am following the [instructions](http://installfest.railsbridge.org/installfest/windows?back=choose_your_operating_system) from Railsbridge Installfest for MS Windows.

I am now stuck at Create a Rails app, step `rails new test_app`. Everything else so far has installed without any issues. I get the following output and error:

`run bundle install
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Resolving dependencies...
Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.org/gems/rake...
10.4.2.gem)
An error occurred while installing rake (10.4.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that 'gem install rake -v '10.4.2' succeeds before bundling.`

I would appreciate help in what I need to do next. I am not very technical and would love some assistance! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do yo have a link to the instructions? It would be nice if you could post that.

Comment: Thank you for looking.  This is the link to instructions, http://installfest.railsbridge.org/installfest/windows?back=choose_your_operating_system

Comment: I would look into http://rubyinstaller.org/ (or http://www.ubuntu.com/)

Comment: @BradWerth, do you suggest I uninstall everything I installed so far and try installing using rubyinstaller.org?  If so, which version would you recommend?

Comment: This post worked for me! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246023/bundle-install-fails-with-ssl-certificate-verification-error

Comment: @moxie_777, you can post an answer with the info in that link - it might help someone in the future! :) (Then you get to answer a question, too!)