# How do you install autoprefixer-rails (5.0.0.2)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried to run the rails server command in my RoR app, but an error came back saying I had to run bundle install before I could run the rails server command.  So I ran the bundle install command, and I ran into another error basically saying that I have to install autoprefixer-rails (5.0.0.2) gem and then run bundle install again. Trying to figure out what the error message really is saying has been a little confusing, so if someone could explain, that would be great!

Here's the error returned in my command line:

```
    $ bundle install
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 10.4.0
Using i18n 0.6.11
Using json 1.8.1
Using minitest 5.4.3
Using thread_safe 0.3.4
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Using activesupport 4.1.8
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using actionview 4.1.8
Using rack 1.5.2
Using rack-test 0.6.2
Using actionpack 4.1.8
Using mime-types 2.4.3
Using mail 2.6.3
Using actionmailer 4.1.8
Using activemodel 4.1.8
Using arel 5.0.1.20140414130214
Using activerecord 4.1.8
Using execjs 2.2.2

Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read
server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.org/gems/autop
refixer-rails-5.0.0.2.gem)
An error occurred while installing autoprefixer-rails (5.0.0.2), and Bundler
cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install autoprefixer-rails -v '5.0.0.2'` succeeds before
bundling.
```

After I ran `gem install autoprefixdr-rails -v '5.0.0.2'` as suggested, the gem got an error. Here's the error returned in my command line:

```
$ gem install autoprefixer-rails -v '5.0.0.2'
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'autoprefixer-rails' (= 5.0.0.2), here is why
:


        Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect retur
    ned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (
    https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Temporary Solution:

On your gemfile change the source from `https://rubygems.org` to just `http://rubygems.org` (remove the 's' after http).

Then bundle install again.

A possible better solution is to run `gem update --system` to fix the problem.  Check out this post for a number of other ideas: [bundle install fails with SSL certificate verification error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246023/bundle-install-fails-with-ssl-certificate-verification-error)

Answer (score 0):

This may be a problem with gems dependencies.
You can simple run

```
gem install autoprefixer-rails -v '5.0.0.2'
```

and

```
bundle install
```

to fix this problem.

Comment: it looks like `SSL` certificate issue so the other answer by @lflores is relevant to this question