# Ruby on rails installation error at cmd on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just finished installing the ruby on rails package(rails 4.1.8).after creating a new directory for it as `"rails new pj"` and it automatically creates folders in the new directory bah when it reaches `"run bundle install"` usually get this error message

> "Gem : : RemoteFetcher: : FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0
>   state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate varify failed
>   https://rubygems.org/gems/rake-10.4.0gem.  An error occurred while
>   installing rake <10.4.2>, and bundler cannot continue. Make sure that
>   gem install rake -v '10.4.2' succeeds before bundling

Comment: possible duplicate of [bundle install fails with SSL certificate verification error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246023/bundle-install-fails-with-ssl-certificate-verification-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run

```
gem install rake -v '10.4.2'
bundle install
bundle update
```

Note:
RailsInstaller is the best package for installing rails on windows.I have tried it on windows8 works great.It includes all required Packages.
RilasInstaller - http://railsinstaller.org/en