# Error while while bundling with Ruby on Rails on Windows platform

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I am trying to create a Ruby On Rails application but I got this error:

[image: certificate verify failed]

Any suggestions? It seems there is a problem downloading gems.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSL Error When installing rubygems, Unable to pull data from 'https://rubygems.org/](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150017/ssl-error-when-installing-rubygems-unable-to-pull-data-from-https-rubygems-o)

Answer (score 0):

Open your Gemfile and change

```
source 'https://rubygems.org
```

to

```
source 'http://rubygems.org
```

then do `bundle install` again.

reference - [bundle install fails with SSL certificate verification error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246023/bundle-install-fails-with-ssl-certificate-verification-error)