# Rails upgrade error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

With help from this excellent group, I was able to install Rails. The next step was to upgrade Rails. I tried both ways as suggested by the documentation and got errors from each...

> C:\Sites>`gem update --system` ERROR:  While executing gem ...
>   (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
>       SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
>
> C:\Sites>`gem install rails` ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rails'
>   (>= 0), here is why:
>             Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B:
>   certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

I reviewed the links given in the comments, but I really did not understand them...sorry. I hope there is a straightforward solution. Thanks

I looked at the Go Rails site and that requires a Linux subsystem which seems like more than I need and was not mentioned by the instructor for the online course. I already have everything installed for running Rails, but the final step is to upgrade Rails from 4.2 to 5.0 and that is where the error occurs.

I also looked at the website that was said to be a possible duplicate and did what it said and no change. Why is this so difficult?

The answer was above. First execute gem sources -a http://rubygems.org and agree to the less secure http, then gem install rails works and upgrades to 5.0.0.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bundle install fails with SSL certificate verification error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246023/bundle-install-fails-with-ssl-certificate-verification-error)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSL Error When installing rubygems, Unable to pull data from 'https://rubygems.org/](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150017/ssl-error-when-installing-rubygems-unable-to-pull-data-from-https-rubygems-o)

Answer (score 0):

The [GoRails](https://gorails.com/setup/windows/10) site has a very good tutorial on how to setup Rais correctly