# bundle exec rake fails with ssl certificate verification message

Tags: ruby, ssl, rake, bundle

I am having an issue with running

```
/local/mis/ruby/bin/bundle exec /local/mis/ruby/bin/rake package OFFLINE=true PINNED=true
```

It throws:

```
[DownloadCache]                  WARN  Unable to download https://java-buildpack.cloudfoundry.org/groovy/index.yml into cache build/staging/resources/cache: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed
rake aborted!
Unable to find cached file for https://java-buildpack.cloudfoundry.org/groovy/index.yml
/local/mis/bamboo/home/xml-data/build-dir/93683714-93782019/java-buildpack/lib/java_buildpack/util/cache/download_cache.rb:75:in `get'
/local/mis/bamboo/home/xml-data/build-dir/93683714-93782019/java-buildpack/rakelib/dependency_cache_task.rb:167:in `get_from_cache'
/local/mis/bamboo/home/xml-data/build-dir/93683714-93782019/java-buildpack/rakelib/dependency_cache_task.rb:159:in `block (2 levels) in uris'
/local/mis/bamboo/home/xml-data/build-dir/93683714-93782019/java-buildpack/rakelib/dependency_cache_task.rb:157:in `each'
/local/mis/bamboo/home/xml-data/build-dir/93683714-93782019/java-buildpack/rakelib/dependency_cache_task.rb:157:in `block in uris'
/local/mis/bamboo/home/xml-data/build-dir/93683714-93782019/java-buildpack/rakelib/dependency_cache_task.rb:156:in `each'
/local/mis/bamboo/home/xml-data/build-dir/93683714-93782019/java-buildpack/rakelib/dependency_cache_task.rb:156:in `uris'
/local/mis/bamboo/home/xml-data/build-dir/93683714-93782019/java-buildpack/rakelib/dependency_cache_task.rb:45:in `initialize'
/local/mis/bamboo/home/xml-data/build-dir/93683714-93782019/java-buildpack/Rakefile:40:in `new'
/local/mis/bamboo/home/xml-data/build-dir/93683714-93782019/java-buildpack/Rakefile:40:in `<top (required)>'
/local/mis/ruby/bin/bundle:22:in `load'
/local/mis/ruby/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
$
```

I am not sure how to get around this.  I am not sure what to fix:  bundle?  rake?  ruby?

I tried to make a .gemrc with

```
:ssl_verify_mode: 0
```

Note to sure format of .gemrc file. Do I need to add the following?

```
- https://cloudfoundry.org
:ssl_verify_mode: 0
```

(guess it is not gem throwing the error since that did not work)

I tried:

```
echo | openssl s_client -connect cloudfoundry.org:443 2>&1 | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > cert.pem
```

I then `cat >> /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt`

Is this correct?  Does ruby, bundle, rake or whatever needs it using this `ca-bundle.crt` file?

I am at a loss on how to get to to be fine with the https location for the java-bundle from cloudfoundry.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246023/bundle-install-fails-with-ssl-certificate-verification-error