# Cannot start rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I tried to `rails server`

> > = Could not find rake-12.0.0 in any of the sources
> >     Run bundle install to install missing gems.

I tried to `bundle update/ install`
It goes to the error msg below .

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your `Gemfile` line from `source 'https://rubygems.org'` to `source 'http://rubygems.org'`

Comment: In my old pc , https works . in the new pc , only http works. Any configuration setting can be made to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this step:

1. `gem install rack`
2. Run `bundle update rake` for updating your Gemfile.lock file.
3. Delete the Gemfile.lock and again `bundle install`.

Comment: ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rack' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)

Comment: This might help you.
`gem update --system`
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246023/bundle-install-fails-with-ssl-certificate-verification-error/10430331#10430331

Answer (score 0):

Try following commands:

```
gem update --system

bundle install
```