# Cannot install ruby on rails because ruby installer cannot find openssl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl

I'm trying to install Ruby 2.6.3 from source for ruby on rails on WSL. Here are the steps I'm taking:
First I check the location of openssl using

```
type -a openssl
```

and I get

```
openssl is /usr/bin/openssl
```

so in the ruby src directory I run 
`./configure --with-openssl-dir=/usr/bin`
Then I run `make`
But I get this message somewhere during the make process:

```
openssl:
        Could not be configured. It will not be installed.
        /mnt/c/Users/MyUserName/Desktop/ruby-2.6.3/ext/openssl/extconf.rb:97: OpenSSL library could not be found. You might want to use --with-openssl-dir=<dir> option to specify the prefix where OpenSSL is installed.
        Check ext/openssl/mkmf.log for more details.
```

Regardless of this warning, I run in the rails src directory the following:

```
gem install rails
```

and get the error:

```
`require': cannot load such file -- openssl (LoadError)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bundle install fails with SSL certificate verification error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246023/bundle-install-fails-with-ssl-certificate-verification-error)

Comment: Try this: `ls -ld /usr/include/openssl/` If it doesn't find, you have to install some more components (platform-dependent, typically `libssl-dev`). The you can re-try configure: `--with-openssl-dir=/usr`

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond, upon following your steps, I don't get the openssl error during make. But I still get the error during sudo make install.

Comment: You might want to quote the error message.

Comment: It's the same error. `require': cannot load such file -- openssl (LoadError)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. It's not enough to run `configure` with the correct directory and `make` again, you have to delete the files that have already been built. I just deleted the build directory and re-extracted from the tar, `make clean` probably would have worked too.