# "gem install rails" produces "Could not find a valid gem"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

The command `gem install rails` produces the following output.

```
$ gem install rails
ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (\>= 0), here is why:
Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

I've tried to solve the issue myself, but haven't found a solution yet. How can I solve this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [bundle install fails with SSL certificate verification error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246023/bundle-install-fails-with-ssl-certificate-verification-error)