# Issue installing bundler - getting 301 "moved" error

Tags: ruby, windows

on a fresh install of an old windows ruby binary, I have an error that I dont know how to get around

environment:

- windows 10
- ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [i386-mingw32] (32 bit version)
- devkit - DevKit-mingw64-32-4.7.2-20130224-1151-sfx

```
PS C:\Users\ALilland> gem install bundler --verbose
HEAD http://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies
200 OK
GET http://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=bundler
301 Moved Permanently
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies)
```

I've been using this ruby version for almost 8 years and have never seen this issue while installing, any ideas on how to get around it?

i've messed with the proxy settings on the machine and i do not currently believe that is the issue

---

on my mac I have an old `ruby 2.4.1` install with rvm, and I can see that it resolves successfully to a different URI

```
$ gem install bundler -v 2.3.26 --verbose
HEAD https://rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies
200 OK
GET https://rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=bundler
200 OK
Downloading gem bundler-2.3.26.gem
GET https://rubygems.org/gems/bundler-2.3.26.gem
Fetching bundler-2.3.26.gem
200 OK
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the SSL certificates can't be verified. This is explained in detail in the [Bundler documentation](https://bundler.io/guides/rubygems_tls_ssl_troubleshooting_guide.html):

## Why am I seeing certificate verify failed?

> If you’ve seen the following SSL error when trying to pull updates from RubyGems: OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
>
> This error happens when your computer is missing a file that it needs to verify that the server behind RubyGems.org is the correct one.
>
> The latest version of RubyGems should fix this problem, so we recommend updating to the current version. To tell RubyGems to update itself to the latest version, run gem update --system. If that doesn’t work, try the manual update process below.
>
> (What do we mean by updating “should fix this problem”? Review the What are these certificates? and How Ruby uses CA certificates sections below to gain a better understanding of the underlying problems.)

### How Ruby uses CA certificates

> The SSL certificate used by RubyGems.org descends from a new-ish root certificate. Ruby (and therefore RubyGems and Bundler) does not have a regularly updated CA bundle to use when contacting websites. Usually, Ruby uses a CA bundle provided by the operating system (OS). On older OSes, this CA bundle can be really old—as in a decade old. Since a CA bundle that old can’t verify the (new-ish) certificate for RubyGems.org, you might see the error in question: certificate verify failed.
>
> Further complicating things, an otherwise unrelated change 18-24 months ago lead to a new SSL certificate being issued for RubyGems.org. This meant the “root” certificate that needed to verify connections changed. So even if you’d previously upgraded RubyGems/Bundler in order to fix the SSL problem, you would need to upgrade again—this time to an even newer version with even newer certificates.

There are [advanced troubleshooting steps](https://bundler.io/guides/rubygems_tls_ssl_troubleshooting_guide.html#the-solutions) available in the documentation that I'm not going to replicate here as they are subject to change and you should always reference the latest instructions.

I can say very broadly though that:

1. You are using a version of Ruby that is end-of-life and will not receive further updates, including security updates
2. You are using a version of Ruby that possibly cannot be made to work even with the troubleshooting steps
3. The safest solution is likely to upgrade to a modern version of Ruby

If you cannot get any of the above steps to work then consider using [`:ssl_verify_mode: 0` in `.gemrc`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10250470/3784008). This should be a last-resort measure as it completely disables SSL certificate validation.