# when i try to install a gem it says this error

Tags: ruby, rubygems

when i tried installing gosu using gem install gosu, it said:
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'gosu' (>= 0), here is why:
Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)

i am using ruby 2.2.2 and devkit version 4.7.2

i dont know how to solve this problem

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246023/bundle-install-fails-with-ssl-certificate-verification-error) are a bunch of "solutions". I would start with `gem update --system`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with devkit but I had a similar issue a while back using rvm to manage ruby versions. The older ruby needed to have updated ssl certificates downloaded.

Does devkit manage your ruby versions? If so, you might look around in the docs to find a way to update your certificates.

If you happen to use rvm on a mac, the command to do this is:
rvm osx-ssl-certs update all

If no one else that is more familiar with devkit chimes in, I'll see if I can help you out more.